# httpd on AWS suddenly stopped working after I set an A record

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, amazon-web-services

So today, I was trying to do two things: get rid of extensions like .php in my domains, and use an A record to point a subdomain I have to the IP of the server on which the site I am developing is running on.

I did both at the same time, then restarted httpd, but when it came back up - I couldn't access the website at all. httpd claims it is running fine. I decided to remove the rewrite rules to see if I had somehow introduced a bug into httpd.conf, but after another restart, it still didn't serve webpages. I tried restarting the server instance - no luck again.

I hadn't changed anything else and the server was serving webpages fine before this. I am trying to access the page using just the IP address, so I don't think the A record could have made a difference either.

The output in httpd's error log is the following:

```
[Wed Aug 10 16:39:44.263098 2016] [suexec:notice] [pid 1843] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using localhost.localdomain. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Wed Aug 10 16:39:44.308130 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 1843] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Aug 10 16:39:44.308701 2016] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 1843] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Wed Aug 10 16:39:44.662464 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1843] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Amazon) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Aug 10 16:39:44.662486 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1843] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Wed Aug 10 16:40:02.960708 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1843] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Wed Aug 10 16:40:03.042697 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 1843] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Aug 10 16:40:03.043290 2016] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 1843] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Wed Aug 10 16:40:03.105719 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1843] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Amazon) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Aug 10 16:40:03.105729 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1843] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Wed Aug 10 16:40:03.105750 2016] [mpm_prefork:warn] [pid 1843] AH00167: long lost child came home! (pid 1968)
```

Any help?

Edit: I used dig on the domain that I pointed with the A-record, and it resolves to the IP (which currently times out but is otherwise the right IP). So it seemingly isn't an issue there, either. I can connect to the server with SSH fine.

Comment: As you say you restarted the server the Server Ip must have changed check it out.

Comment: @error2007s IP is still the same - just double checked.

Comment: Can you paste your httpd config file?

Comment: @error2007s Here it is: http://pastebin.com/raw/P8bCSYzw